# Why does shadowing not release a borrowed reference?

Tags: rust

It seems that shadowing a variable does not release the borrowed reference it holds. The following code does not compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 40;
    let r1 = &mut a;
    let r1 = "shadowed";
    let r2 = &mut a;
}
```

With the error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:5:19
  |
3 |     let r1 = &mut a;
  |                   - first mutable borrow occurs here
4 |     let r1 = "shadowed";
5 |     let r2 = &mut a;
  |                   ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
6 | }
  | - first borrow ends here
```

I would expect the code to compile because the first reference `r1` is shadowed before borrowing the second reference `r2`. Obviously, the first borrow lives until the end of the block although it is no longer accessible after line 4. Why is that the case?

Comment: Note: borrowing is lexical at the moment, however there's work to change this. In the future (once Non Lexical Lifetimes: NLL are implemented) rustc will notice that since `r1` is unused by the time `r2` is formed, it's okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR: Shadowing is about name-lookup, borrowing is about lifetimes.**

From a compiler point of view, variables have no name:

```
fn main() {
    let mut __0 = 40;
    let __1 = &mut __0;
    let __2 = "shadowed";
    let __3 = &mut __0;
}
```

This is not very readable for a human being, so the language allows us to use descriptive names instead.

Shadowing is an allowance on *reusing names*, which for the lexical scope of the "shadowing" variable will resolve the name to the "shadowing" one (`__2` here) instead of the "original" one (`__1` here).

However just because the old one can no longer be accessed does not mean it no longer *lives*: *Shadowing != Assignment*. This is especially notable with different scopes:

```
fn main() {
    let i = 3;
    for i in 0..10 {
    }
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Will always print `3`: once the shadowing variable's scope ends, the name resolves to the original again!

Comment: This makes sense to me, although it seems like an "optimization" the compiler could easily know about. Your comment to the question clarified that: *Because it's not yet implemented.*

Comment: @kazemakase: Shadowing and NLLs are... only partially related. NLLs, despite its name, does not affect lifetimes but only borrowing state. In the example with a loop I showed, even though `i` is shadowed in the loop, the outer `i` still is usable afterward. If it were a borrow, the borrow would be active across the loop: shadowing is purely *cosmetic*. If you want to "change" the borrow status, once NLL is implemented, you will be able to either (1) re-assign to the variable or (2) `drop` it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not like the original `r1` ceases to exist after it becomes shadowed; consider the MIR produced for your code without the last line (`r2` binding):

```
fn main() -> () {
    let mut _0: ();                      // return pointer
    scope 1 {
        let mut _1: i32;                 // "a" in scope 1 at src/main.rs:2:9: 2:14
        scope 2 {
            let _2: &mut i32;            // "r1" in scope 2 at src/main.rs:3:9: 3:11
            scope 3 {
                let _3: &str;            // "r1" in scope 3 at src/main.rs:4:9: 4:11
            }
        }
    }

    bb0: {
        StorageLive(_1);                 // scope 0 at src/main.rs:2:9: 2:14
        _1 = const 40i32;                // scope 0 at src/main.rs:2:17: 2:19
        StorageLive(_2);                 // scope 1 at src/main.rs:3:9: 3:11
        _2 = &mut _1;                    // scope 1 at src/main.rs:3:14: 3:20
        StorageLive(_3);                 // scope 2 at src/main.rs:4:9: 4:11
        _3 = const "shadowed";           // scope 2 at src/main.rs:4:14: 4:24
        _0 = ();                         // scope 3 at src/main.rs:1:11: 5:2
        StorageDead(_3);                 // scope 2 at src/main.rs:5:2: 5:2
        StorageDead(_2);                 // scope 1 at src/main.rs:5:2: 5:2
        StorageDead(_1);                 // scope 0 at src/main.rs:5:2: 5:2
        return;                          // scope 0 at src/main.rs:5:2: 5:2
    }
}
```

Note that when `"shadowed"` becomes bound (`_3`), it doesn't change anything related to the original `r1` binding (`_2`); the name `r1` no longer applies to the mutable reference, but the original variable still exists.

I wouldn't consider your example a very useful case of shadowing; its usual applications, e.g. bodies of loops, are much more likely to utilize it.